# adding a custom StumbleUpon badge to a page

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to use the stumbleupon api for a custom made stumbleupon badge. I'm reading the documentation but can't figure it out what I'm supposed to do.

I'm adding the link to my page, but all it returns is a JSON array. Do i have to do something with the sample JSON response provided on he doc page? I've never used ajax like this and am quite confused. Here's Links to the sample page im trying to link from, and the api doc. I promise both both pages are very short.

Many thanks in advance to anyone who can point me in the right direction!

http://webnamehere.com/

http://www.stumbleupon.com/help/badge-api-documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to parse the items out of the JSON and use them to generate the HTML for the badge.

Take a look here for some more info and examples: [json.org](http://www.json.org/js.html)